# Xceed datagrid cell editor disabled for null values

Tags: datagridview

I am using an Xceed datagrid to display data retreived from database. I would like to allow users the ability to edit the values that are being displayed on the grid. But it appears that when there is a null value in the underlying datasource, the corresponding cell becomes readonly. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly set the CellEditor like this...

`<xcdg:Column FieldName="From" Title="From" CellEditor="{DynamicResource dateTimeEditor}" Width="*" >`